# Old science fiction story about depositing a dollar in a bank and allowing the money to grow for 40 generations

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find an old science-fiction story about depositing a dollar in a bank and allowing the money to grow for 40 generations.

Comment: I posted an answer to your question. If it's the right answer, you can "accept" it by clicking on the check mark next to it. If it's not the answer you were looking for, please let us know and try to add more details to your description if you can.

Comment: Of course there's also the mention in Hitch-Hiker's Guide To The Galaxy of depositing one penny in a bank account now to pay for a meal at the Restaurant at the End of the Universe.

Comment: This is surely not what you look for, but Andreas Eschbach gives this idea an IMHO nice spin in “Eine Billion Dollar”, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eine_Billion_Dollar

Comment: There is also a [Futurama episode with a very similar plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Fishful_of_Dollars)

Comment: Can't find the book now, but in "Time Enough For Love" Lazarus Long presents a scenario along these lines, with the final value of the interest, and the kicker, "by which time it will be worth precisely nothing".

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about the particular story you're trying to think of, as [this is something of a trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CompoundInterestTimeTravelGambit). (You could ask for the _oldest_ version of the trope, but that would be a different question.) Is the "40 generations" an exact detail that you're confident of, or your own summary? When did you read the story, and do you have an idea of when it might have been written? What else can you remember about the plot?

Comment: @user14111 Since there is a story with exactly 40 generations mentioned, you might well be right. I still think it's a poorly written question, though, because it doesn't actually tell us these are specific details to look for, and "old" tells us nothing (is something written in the year 2000 old? it is if you weren't born then!).

Comment: Found it: "*$100 placed at 7 percent interest compounded quarterly for 200 years will increase to more than $l00,000,000—by which time it will be worth nothing.*" From "The Notebooks of Lazarus Long", quoted in "Time Enough For Love" by Robert Heinlein. Interestingly I make it a mere $75,293,162.

Comment: Hey, what about inflation and global shifts in currency rates?

Comment: @PaulJohnson Google tells me that 100 * 1.0175^800 = $106,545,305.

Comment: @PaulJohnson I see what you did wrong. $75,293,162 is what you get with **annual** compounding over 200 years. Quarterly compounding will get you over $100 million

Answer (score 30):

["John Jones's Dollar"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57490), a short story by [Harry Stephen Keeler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Stephen_Keeler), originally published in 1915, available at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/26867). The story is told in the form of a history lecture in the future:

> On the 201st day of the year 3221 A.D., the professor of history at the University of Terra seated himself in front of the Visaphone and prepared to deliver the daily lecture to his class, the members of which resided in different portions of the earth.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "But to return to our subject. In the year 1921, one of these numerous John Joneses performed an apparently inconsequential action which caused the name of John Jones to go down in history. What did he do?
>
> "He proceeded to one of these banks, known at that time as 'The First National Bank of Chicago,' and deposited there, one of these disks—a silver Dollar—to the credit of a certain individual. And this individual to whose credit the Dollar was deposited was no other person than the fortieth descendant of John Jones who stipulated in paper which was placed in the files of the bank, that the descendancy was to take place along the oldest child of each of the generations which would constitute his posterity.
>
> "The bank accepted the Dollar under that understanding, together with another condition imposed by this John Jones, namely, that the interest was to be compounded annually. That meant that at the close of each year, the bank was to credit the account of John Jones's fortieth descendant with three one-hundredths of the account as it stood at the beginning of the year.
>
> "History tells us little more concerning this John Jones—only that he died in the year 1931, or ten years afterward, leaving several children.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112384/discussion-on-answer-by-user14111-old-science-fiction-story-about-depositing-a-d).

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw out Mack Reynold's "Compound Interest".  It was an answer to a previous question:  [What is this story about an investing time traveller?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175854/what-is-this-story-about-an-investing-time-traveller)

Comment: The OP's description is quite terse but it specifically says "a dollar" and "40 generations" which exactly matches the Keeler story but not the Reynolds. When the question gives us so few clues, I don't think we should ignore any of them. Also, when time travel is a major element of a story, it usually gets mentioned.

Comment: This is how you purchase a meal at Milliway's - after you've eaten it.

Comment: @mcalex Also I'm pretty certain Heinlein uses a similar idea, possibly in *The Number of the Beast* as that's his book I've read most recently

Comment: I understand and agree, but was offering the Reynolds as a fallback.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about 40 generations, but the Futurama episode "A Fishful of Dollars" (S1 E6) contains this plotline:

> As the crew scrounges up bail money, Fry notices that the bank where he used to have an account has remained in business. He still has his ATM card and remembers his PIN code: the price of a cheese pizza and large soda at Panucci's Pizza, where he used to work. The account had contained 93 cents in 1999, but after accruing interest at 2.25% per year for 1,000 years, the balance is now $4.3 billion.

Comment: I'd imagine the OP is after a written work but seeing as it's not clarified this seems like a good answer if it's actually a cartoon.